# single line node API initialization

Tags: node.js

Sometimes when I import node js modules I need to import and then instantiate the class. I would like to do it with a single line (it might be a very basic question for nodejs but my JavaScript knowledge is limited).

ex:

```
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new JWT({
    email: 'asd',
    key: 'abc',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  });
```

I find weird to have a const which will only be used once in my code to instantiate another const.
I would like to do something like:

```
const client = new require('google-auth-library')({
        email: 'asd',
        key: 'abc',
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
      });
```

Is it possible? What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't worry about such tiny things as they don't matter performance-wise and you get better readability. However, if you insist then you can use below code but I won't recommend and more not even bother

```
const client = new (require('google-auth-library')).JWT({
        email: 'asd',
        key: 'abc',
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
      });
```

. . .